# how do i using absolute paths in Next.js use typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js

`main-layout.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import { TLayout } from '@types';
import { Header } from '@common';
    
export function MainLayout({children}:TLayout) {
    return (
       <div>
        {children}
       </div>
      )
    }
```

`index.ts`

```
export * from './main-layout'
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
"paths": {
    "@layouts"["./components/layouts/index.ts"],
}
```

Terminal

```
error - ./pages/_app.tsx:5:0
    Module not found: Can't resolve '@layouts'
```

In my project I can't export from tsx file to ts file, while using ts to export ts can be used normally, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When settings the paths you are missing a `:` between you alias and its paths. It should be:

```
"@layouts" : ["./components/layouts/index.ts"],
```

Also make sure in your tsconfig.json that you have added a baseurl property. The most common example is:

```
    "baseUrl": ".",
```

Finally, most of the time you want to alias paths to folders rather than files. But that's up to you.

```
"@layouts" : ["./components/layouts/*"],
```